# Should I use Factory Method design pattern for this problem?

Tags: design-patterns, factory-method

I'm working on an application which needs to open a database file. There are 2 "versions" of this database: one of them is more general data storage, and the other contains "less" information. That being said, database table structures are different, so I need to issue different queries to get "same" information from each of them.

My first thought is to create a query factory abstract interface, which will only have pure virtual methods returning the queries:

```
class IQueryFactory
{
public:
    virtual QString getNames() const = 0;
    virtual QString getSurnames() const = 0;
    // ...
};
```

and have this interface implemented for both "versions" of database:

```
class GeneralQueryFactory : public IQueryFactory
{
public:
    QString getNames() const override
    {
        return "SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM People;";
    }

    QString getSurnames() const override
    {
        return "SELECT DISTINCT Surname FROM People;";
    }

    // ...
}

class SpecificQueryFactory : public IQueryFactory
{
public:
    QString getNames() const override
    {
        return "SELECT DISTINCT FirstName FROM Employees;";
    }

    QString getSurnames() const override
    {
        return "SELECT DISTINCT LastName FROM Employees;";
    }

    // ...
}
```

I'm creating an instance of `GeneralQueryFactory` and `SpecificQueryFactory` at program startup, then when a database is to be loaded, I check if some table in database, and based on that store the corresponding query factory pointer with the database name in map:

```
GeneralQueryFactory generalFactory;
SpecificQueryFactory specificFactory;

// ...

if (...)
    dbInfo.add(dbPath, &app.generalFactory);
else
    dbInfo.add(dbPath, &app.specificFactory);
```

Later I use the query factory as follows (in another function):

```
auto queryFct = dbInfo.getQueryFactory(dbPath);
QSqlQuery sqlQuery(queryFct->getNames());
sqlQuery.exec();
// ...
```

I wanna know if this is done correctly. Is the usage of this design pattern correct for this problem? What can I improve? Thanks.

Comment: There is no factory in your code. You have an abstract class and two concrete classes that implement it (basic polymorphism). And you have a map, which is effectively an implementation of the strategy pattern.

Comment: Have you considered using the repository pattern instead, i.e. moving the query logic into the classes? To me that would seem like a more natural design, whereas your current classes just describe a name → SQL snippet mapping. You don't even need virtual methods right now, you'd get the same effect with multiple values of `struct Queries{QString getNames, getSurnames;}`.

Comment: @DavidArno I read about the strategy pattern, and my bad that's what I implemented.
@amon my `dbInfo` acts as repository, it has both `add` and `get` methods for query strategy. what else should be different?

Answer (score 3):

1. Your "Factory" is not a factory (ar least not in the way the [GoF book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) defines it). But I think this is just a misnomer, what you have shown us here is the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). So consider to rename these classes to match the correct GoF terms.

   A **factory method** is one which makes the decision which strategy object to use, i.e.

   ```
    IQueryStrategy &PickQueryStrategy()
    {
        if (...)
          return &app.generalFactory;
       else
          return &app.specificFactory;
    }
   ```
2. If providing different sets of static strings is really the only thing which is required here, the strategy pattern is probably overdesigned. Two string lists which are kept in a dictionary, where the database type is some enum used as the key value for this dictionary requires less boilerplate code and would be probably simpler. The `dbInfo` object then just gets one of those lists assigned, and pick the right query by using another enum as an index.

   The code which uses this list would then look like this:

   ```
   auto queryList = dbInfo.getQueryList(dbPath);
   QSqlQuery sqlQuery(queryList[QueryIndex::FirstName]);
   ```

   However, as we don't know your "real" code, which may be more complex, using the strategy pattern may be perfectly justified, you have to decide this for yourself if there will be some different behaviour for each of the databases required.

Comment: this `if` block is in the code that opens the file (only at which point I know the database version). So from there I need to *set* the query strategy. But yes, the idea of map is better. I think the key should be a string, because adding another version of database would be difficult with enum. And how should the concrete query be taken from list (or maybe unordered_set?)?

Comment: @bb8: Sure you have to set the query strategy with some code like `dbInfo.add(PickQueryStrategy())`. But in the explanation of the term "Factory method", the part `dbInfo.add` does not belong, that's why I left it out. If you think a map is sufficient for your case, then go ahead. An `enum` as a key gives you some type safety, similar to the type safety you got from from strategy classes. If you think you don't need that safety, you can use a string.

Comment: okay, my question was mostly about retrieving the concrete query from the map, i.e. the type of the values in the map, is it list/unordered_set/map? Because I can't see how would I get the necessary query from that list (storage). By name?

Comment: @bb8: by a second enum (see my edit).

Comment: isn't enum "dangerous" in this case? what if someone goes ahead and adds new value in the middle of enum? although that should not be of concern...?

Comment: @bb8:you should use enums with explicitly assigned values, of course. Or constants, if you prefer that. Or, you implement this by a  "translation map", where the translation goes from one SQL/DB variant to another: so you make a function where you pass the "general" query as an argument: `getTranslatedQuery(dbInfo, "SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM People")`, and depending on the chosen DB, either that query is returned, or a "translated" one which fits to the "special" DB.

Comment: ... so the "general" query becomes the key into the map by itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105352/discussion-between-bb8-and-doc-brown).

Comment: I have one more question. where should query strings be stored? currently i declare them as `const extern` in header some file and define them in source file, i.e. they're static. i include this file in query strategy file, and return appropriate query. but this approach makes queries accessible outside query strategy too which i don't like. now i have only header file for strategies, where methods are inline. so i'm thinking about moving them to source file in order to create query strings in source file (in order to hide them), but then they won't be inline. please advice what to do

Comment: @bb8: what about implementing your "query strategy" object, but not with one method per SQL, but with just one method in the interface, which gets an enum as a parameter and returns the appropriate SQL string? That offers you the opportunity to keep the query strings inside the CPP, without declaring them `extern`.